# SQL count date range

Tags: sql, date, range

I'm trying to query my SQL database to get the number of orders made by each client within a certain date range.

I have a list of orders as follows

```
CustomerName       ClientID        DateOrdered
Customer No.2         10            2011-11-25
Customer No.3         11            2011-10-15
Customer No.3         11            2011-11-25
```

and I want to be able to find out how many orders have been made by a specific client for example between 2011-11-1 and 2011-11-30, this should result in :

```
CustomerName       ClientID        Number
Customer No.3         11             1
Customer No.2         10             1
```

So far I've managed to get this

```
SELECT CustomerName, ClientID, COUNT(*) AS Number      
FROM Orders t     
GROUP BY CustomerName, ClientID      
HAVING COUNT(*) =      
(SELECT MAX(Number)         
FROM          
(SELECT CustomerName, ClientID, COUNT(*) AS Number             
FROM Orders            
GROUP BY CustomerName, ClientID ) x       
WHERE CustomerName = t.CustomerName )
```

Which gives me every order the customer has ever made

```
CustomerName       ClientID        Number
Customer No.3         11             2
Customer No.2         10             1
```

Am I going about the right way to solve this or is there a simpler way which I've completely overlooked!

Comment: out of topic: Why you have CustomerID and CustomerName in the order table? To have any other customer info you will have to join with customer tablw. If you mistype the client name and you correct it you will need to revise the orders table to change there as well. So only the foreign key customer Id would be more accurate...

Comment: It shouldn't actually be in there! Thanks for reminding me to take it out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select CustomerName, ClientID, count(*)
from
(
    select CustomerName, ClientID
    from Orders
    where datediff(mm, DateOrdered, getdate()) <= 1
 )a
group by CustomerName, ClientID
```

What this does is utilize a subquery that filters the rows by the dates in a given month (that seems to be what you are looking for).  Then it groups by the `CustomerName` and `ClientID` and gets the sum of their orders.

Comment: [`sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) of ...? Does it really work in SQL Server? `datediff(mm, DateOrdered, getdate())` - will it use index if it's available?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would datediff be a better option than a between in this case?

Answer (score 9):

Should work fine:

```
select CustomerName, ClientID, count(*) as Number
from Orders
where DateOrdered between '20111101' and '20111130'
group by CustomerName, ClientID
```

Comment: @MichaelPowaga, why use a subquery?

Comment: @MarkBannister, it's not necessary but it changes nothing in execution plan (at last in my case).

Comment: @MichaelPowaga, so why use it?

Comment: @MarkBannister, you are right in this case subquery was useless. I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ClientID, max(CustomerName), count(*) 
from Orders 
where DateOrdered between '2011-11-01' and '2011-11-30'
group by ClientID
```

Depending on database, the syntax of the DateOrdered selection may need to be varied.

Comment: dont forget to add 'start_date 00:00:00' AND 'end_date 23:59:59' if your variables are like (Y-m-d)

Comment: The question implied dates only - no times - or else I would have put ... `DateOrdered >= '2011-11-01' and DateOrdered < '2011-12-01'`. An order could occur at 23:59:59.1, which would be missed by the `between` syntax.

Comment: For date ranges, you are often better served by using `DateOrdered >= '2011-11-01' AND DateOrdered  < '2011-12-01'`.  By making the end date exclusive (using `<`), you don't need to care if the date field includes a time or not.

Comment: Well I never really got the point with this issue,... but more than once I found myself in troubles because of this. I never investigate it, but always worked... :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  c.CustomerName,
  count(o.OrderID) as Orders
FROM
  orders o
JOIN clients c ON o.ClientID = c.ClientID
WHERE
  o.DateOrdered BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-11-20'
GROUP BY c.ClientID ;
```