# count dates between range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count the dates between a range. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297080/sql-count-date-range) but this is not working for me.

Here is a sample of my table

```
repo   | revision    | date         | author

test   | 1           | 01/01/2011   | chris
test   | 2           | 01/01/2011   | chris
test   | 3           | 01/02/2011   | chris
```

So I want to count the dates that are equivalent for a repo... So in this case it would return `2` for `01/01/2011` and `1` for `01/02/2011`

Here is the closest I think I have gotten to accomplishing this...

```
select date, count(*)
from SVNLogEntry
where repo = 'test' and date between '01/01/2011' and '01/01/2017'
group by date;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the number of distinct dates, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
select repo, count(distinct date)
from SVNLogEntry
where repo = 'test' and date between '2011-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
group by repo;
```

To get them per `repo`, then use `group by repo`, not `group by date`.